# Why use dropout in feedforward?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, dropout, forward-backward

Maybe I am just confused by what is the point of using dropout in the feed-forward? Wouldn't be better to forward the input with the whole network and then use the dropout only in the back-prop to limit the modifications of weights and biases of a limited number of neurons and hence reduce overfitting?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of dropout is to average over the exponentially many thinned networks that arise from randomly removing units. Your suggestion of dropping out units during backprop only doesn’t achieve this, because all units were used during the forward pass.

Answer (score 0):

The motivation behind Dropout varies - there's the biologically inspired prevention of "co-adaptation", and there's the ensemble explanation (which is very hand-wavy in my opinion, and I'm not convinced by the Baldi and Sadowski paper either). As in other parts of NN it's not so theoretically driven as it is empirically driven. I think your idea is valid, the only thing is that it needs to be tested and experimented with.

[I implemented this now](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wRu8-LIgW69ss1sQATMM9Q9ufbSluwyh?usp=sharing) (adjusted a manual Dropout implementation I had in numpy): from a very preliminary analysis on the MNIST data this does seem to improve the validation accuracy - even more than regular Dropout (on a specific architecture, LR, # of epochs, optimizer, etc.), but the trajectory of the train/validation accuracy doesn't look like what you would expect in Dropout: the training accuracy goes very high fast, and the validation accuracy stumbles behind - which is similar to simple networks without Dropout.